# Can I assign claims to role and then assign roles to user in .NET Core?

Tags: .net-core, claims-based-identity, asp.net-core-identity, user-roles

We have four claims:

```
CanViewPosts, CanEditPosts, CanAddPosts, CanDeletePosts
```

Now, I want to create a role `Moderator` and assign two claims `CanViewPosts, CanEditPosts` to this role.

Then, I create a user with mail `moderator@example.com` and assign the `Moderator` role to this user.

I can assign roles to a user, but I want to dynamically assign claims to a role. Because, I will give multiple users, a same role.

How can I implement this in .NET Core 5 ?

Comment: Hi @Mehedi Hasan Kajol, where you stuck in now? What you have done now, pls share enough code and then we can know how to help you.

Comment: I have done this by going through an article posted by Mukesh (https://codewithmukesh.com/).
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can assign claims and roles in identity server, if you are using identity server use claim type of role and claim value is CanViewPosts, CanEditPosts